# my ip looks different in visual studio code when I change places

Tags: android, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I don't understand why my ip looks different when I change places.
When I'm in working place, the ip looks like a public ip like this`58.122.101.xxx`.
But when I'm in my home, the ip looks like a private ip like this `192.168.0.6` in visual studio code.
I don't understand this and the big problem is that I can't open the private site in my android webview.
When I run my website in working plcae, the webview show this well. But when I run my website in my home,  changing the public ip to private ip, I can't see the website.
Even though I set the package.json setting, it's not working.

```
  "private": false
```

how to understand this weird happening?

Answer (score 0):

`yarn dev --hostname 0.0.0.0` should do it.
More details [here](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/)

Then, you can access it w/ something like `192.168.0.6:3000`.

If you want to expose it publicly wo/ too much struggle, you could use one of those 2 modules too: https://modules.nuxtjs.org/?q=expose&orderBy=desc